# We lost 75% of sales after switching from Magento 1 to Magento 2. How to get back up to 100%?

Tags: seo

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
Extensions from Amasty
```

We have migrated from Magento 1.9.4 to Magento 2.4.2-p1 using the Magento Migration Tool about a week ago but now we are getting 75% less sales on both of the websites/stores.

I randomly checked the URLs of 100 products and out of those, 30 resolved correctly on the new Magento 2 website and 70 went to a 404 Error on the new Magento website. I will set up permanent redirects for these.

**What else can we do to get back to the same amount of customer visits/sales that we had before the Migration? Would switching back to Magento 1 bring the sales back?**

Answer (score 2):

This can't be answered generally.

When 70% of your URLs return a 404, the migration seems to be really broken.

I'd expect that many seo optimizations are also no longer intact.

Another issue is that customers may experience server performance problems that you don't even yet know of, or they don't understand the new UI, or there are errors in the ordering process you didn't find while testing.

Find a trusted developer or agency and have them audit your site. This should give much better results than asking such a general question here.